# Arduino processing multiple files order problem

Tags: arduino, processing

I have an Arduino sketch that was one file written in "processing 3" ( I don't know exactly what is the language I write in).

I divided the file into two parts. The first part contains the setup and loop. 
The second part is a part of code defined as a single class.

I try to compile the sketch and the first file does not recognize the existence of the second one ( a second tab with that file is created into the IDE environment ).

If I create a third file and I empty the first file migrating the code from the first to the third ( leaving the first file empty ) the sketch does compile correctly, meaning that the order is important.

What do I miss ?

Comment: You should post your code

Comment: Optimally, you experiment with some small sample code in different files. That's more fun for others to read and easier to see an error (even for you yourself)  
And yes, .ino files are concatenated (order by name) and order matters, regarding declaration of classes, types and variables. Arduino IDE just adds function declarations to the top of the combined .inos

Answer (score 1):

Without more details or code to look at I can only provide a few pointers:

- [Processing](https://processing.org/download/) is for desktop applications, not microcontrollers like Arduino and relies on the Java Virtual Machine
- There is a separate [Arduino IDE](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software) which compiles code for microcontrollers, not desktops: behind the scenes it compiles c++ code (This is the editor you want to use)
- There might be a bit of confusion since the Arduino IDE started as a modified clone of the Processing IDE and are therefore very similar. While the editors are (very) similar, the languages (Java for Processing, c++ for Arduino) and target CPU architectures are very different. To add to the confusion, old Arduino sketches used to have the .pde extension (same as Processing sketches), while now it uses the .ino extension.

[image: Processing IDE Window]

[image: Arduino IDE Window]

**TLDR;** If your code has `setup()` and `loop()` it's Arduino code: use the Arduino IDE to select the correct microcontroller to compile.

(`setup()` and `draw()` is what a Processing sketch uses)

Regarding the code in the separate class, it could be a separate .pde or .ino file, or even a .h file (in which case it needs to be `#include`d from the main tab)

I advise posting the code for more accurate answers.

Comment: You mean that I am writing in C++ when using the arduino ide or what am I writting in ?

Comment: Yes, you are using C++ when using the Arduino IDE. To see more enable **Arduino > Preferences > Show verbose output during compilation** (and optionally upload). If you're using an Arduino Uno microcontroller you'll see the avr-gcc compile to a temp folder. In terms of the other class, as mentioned in my answer above, there is a bit of a difference if the class is defined in another .ino file or a .h file. If the answer was helpful vote/mark it accordingly :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is found at: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=534474.0

Accordingly it seems that:

"the Arduino IDE first loads the principal file and then loads the other files in alphabetical order."

This is conceptually wrong but actually that is the situation and I have checked that it works loading at first the principal file and afterwards other files.